# Mudflap and pointer arrays

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I've just implemented a pretty complicated piece of software, but my school's testing system won't take it.
The system uses the so-called mudflap library which should be able to prevent illegal memory accesses better. As a consequence, my program generates segfaults when run on the school's testing system (I submit the source code and the testing system compiles it for itself, using the mudflap library).

I tried to isolate the problematic code in my program, and it seems that it all boils down to something as simple as pointer arrays. Mudflap doesn't seem to like them.

Below is a piece of some very simple code with that works with a pointer array:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
char** rows;
rows=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*3);
rows[0]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
rows[1]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
rows[2]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
strcpy(rows[0], "abc");
strcpy(rows[1], "abc");
strcpy(rows[2], "abc");
free(rows[0]); free(rows[1]); free(rows[2]);
free(rows);
return 0;
```

This will generate a segfault with mudflap. In my opinion, this is a perfectly legal code.
Could you please explain to me what is wrong with it, and why it generates a segfault with mudflap?

Note: The program should be compiled under an amd64 linux system with g++ using the following commands:

```
    export MUDFLAP_OPTIONS='-viol-segv -print-leaks';
    g++ -Wall -pedantic -fmudflap -fmudflapir -lmudflap -g file.cpp
```

Comment: This is NOT correct code. You allocating 3 bytes, not 3*sizeof(char*). You're also leaking memory.

Comment: I fixed the code. That was really just a typo. The point is -- this version doesn't work either. (Now I'm even freeing the allocated memory even though there's no point in doing it here.)

Answer (score 3):

You have at least one problem here:

```
char** rows;
rows=(char**)malloc(3);
```

This allocates 3 bytes.  On most platforms the allocator probably has a minimum of at least 4 bytes which lets you get away with overwriting the buffer a bit.  I'm guessing your mudflap library is more strict in its checking and catches the overwrite.

However, if you want an array of 3 `char *` pointers, you probably need at least 12 bytes.

Try changing these lines to:

```
char** rows;
rows=(char**)malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
```

EDIT:  Based on your modified code, I agree it looks correct now.  The only thing I can suggest is that perhaps `malloc()` is failing and causing a NULL pointer access.  If thats not the case it sounds like a bug or misconfiguration of mudflap.

Comment: My apologies. Yeah, you're right. THe first parameter to malloc should have been sizeof(char*).

The problem is. It doesn't work either. :/

Comment: There is only one parameter to malloc().  Do you mean `3 * sizeof(char *)`?

Comment: I fixed the code in my question. The point is that it that mudflap still doesn't like it :/.

Comment: Added to my answer.  Agree it looks correct.  Maybe malloc is returning NULL?  Shouldn't be for such small sizes, but worth checking.

Comment: Nope. It isn't. As a matter of fact, this isn't even the code I'm really concerned with. It's just something I wrote quickly to illustrate the problem. In the real code, I'm working with some pretty large arrays, and I tend to think that if I had made an error there, it would've generated a *REAL* segfault (It doesn't, the code otherwise works 100%). Also, I assert() each allocation I make in my real code, so a failed allocation would've been very easy to spot. This all seems to be isolated to mudflap. Unfortunately mudflap is the component I'm dependent on here.

Comment: What do you get if you add "-trace-calls -verbose-trace" to your MUDFLAP_OPTIONS?  Looking at the choices here:  http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Mudflap_Pointer_Debugging

Comment: So it looks like its upset about one of the free's for the 4-byte allocations.  If you add printf's like `printf("alloc 4 = 0x%x\n", rows[2])` you can probably line up the addresses in the mudflap output to your variables.  Unfortunately I'm not sure I will be able to help much further.  Have you also tried this on another machine or vintage of linux?  Perhaps there is a library issue with your particular development environment.  Sorry I don't have the answer.  Best of luck!